# Android Maven IntelliJ project with git submodules

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea

We have a maven project with Git submodules `contrib/holo-everywhere` and `contrib/ActionBarSherlock`

Root pom.xml describes modules like that:

```
<module>contrib/holo-everywhere/resbuilder</module>
<module>contrib/holo-everywhere/library</module>
<module>contrib/holo-everywhere/addons/preferences</module>
<module>contrib/holo-everywhere/addons/slidingmenu</module>
<module>contrib/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock</module>
```

maven build from console works perfectly, but when project is improted into IntelliJ IDEA errors occurs.

Each and every pom.xml like `contrib/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/pom.xml` can't resolve dependecy version from dependecy management in it's projects parent pom. In this case it's `contrib/ActionBarSherlock/pom.xml`

**contrib/ActionBarSherlock/pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    <version>${android.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

**contrib/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

This happens only with these submodules that are in `contrib` dir. We have maven modules that depend on parent pom - their dependencies are resolved fine.

Is it a bug or should I import projects some other way?

Comment: At the `contrib/ActionBarSherlock/pom.xml`, do you define the `<dependency>` under the `<dependencies>` at the project level or under the `<dependencyManagement>`?

Comment: Under `<dependencyManagement>`. In ActionBarSherlock and holo-everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<relativePath>` to parent `pom.xml` was missing.